# Layout in _layout.cshtml in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have a layout having three container: left container , central container and right container in the _layout page.I tried with the following code but it dosen't respond with the expected result.

```
<body>
        <header>
            @Html.Partial("_header")
        </header>       

         <div class="row">

             <div class="col-lg-4 well">
                 hello there lcont
                 @RenderBody()
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-4 well" >
                  Central container
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-4 well ">
                 right container
             </div>


         </div>



        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
```

Instead of getting three divs side by side in a single row i get three different rows.

[image]

**EDIT**

I changed col-lg-4 to col-md-4 and it worked as it is suposed to.Any explanation i am confused.

Comment: `<divs>` are block elements, so that's the default. You need to style the elements to get the layout out you want. Refer [simple fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wqyayss/) using floats and width

Comment: I have used the bootstrap and according to bootstrap it is supposed to have 3 container in a row side by side each occuping the equal width

Comment: Would have been useful to have mentioned that in your question. Have you included the relevant bootstrap .css files?

Comment: And the first div has class `col-lg-4` and the other 2 have `lg-col-4` Is that correct?

Comment: The use of col-lg-2 signified the bootstrap is being used.Yes all the required files are appended

Comment: Only if you know bootstrap

Comment: Sorry about "lg-col-4" that was mistakenly printed

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `section`s and `RenderSection()` instead of `RenderBody()`.

In your `_Layout.cshtml`, render the sections like this,

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 well">
        hello there lcont
        @RenderSection("Left")
    </div>

    <div class="lg-col-4 well">
        @RenderSection("Center")
    </div>

    <div class="lg-col-4 well ">
        @RenderSection("Right")
    </div>


</div>
```

And in each `content.cshtml` page, divide the section contents like this:

```
@section Left{
   <span> left content goes here</span> and here
}

@section Center{
   <div> Center content </div>
}

@section Right{
  any html here goes to <aside> Right content </aside>
}
```

***NOTE:***
If your problem is that `div`s are coming below each other, make sure you include the bootstrap or relevant css that provide grid system as I see from your use of `col-lg-*` classes.